# Método para automatizar a chamada de Forms em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, mdi

Eis o que eu estou tentando fazer

Estou criando uma aplicação em C#, MainFrame é a MDI Pai, e eu possuo outras janelas também.
O que eu quero é usar uma classe chamada "FormCaller" para chamar outros Forms de forma automatica, assim nao preciso escrever sempre a mesma coisa.

Eis o codigo:

```
namespace StudentManager
{
class FormCaller
{


    public static MainFrame MAIN = new MainFrame();
    public static CadastrarAluno REG = new CadastrarAluno();



    public void CallForm(Form window)
    {
        window.MdiParent = MAIN;
        window.Show();
    }

}
}
```

Assim, o que eu estou tentando fazer é chamar uma Form nova, do tipo MDI CHILD, usando um metodo personalizado:

```
FormCaller caller;
private void method(...) {
   caller.CallForm(FormCaller.CAD);
}
```

Eu não sei se isso é possivel em C#, ja fiz o mesmo em JAVA e deu certo, alguem pode me dizer se existe alguma forma conhecida de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se eu entendi direito, você quer chamar formulários e colocá-los como filhos do MDIParent FormCaller. Eu fiz algo semelhante, mas antes, vamos colocar alguns pontos...

A forma como você está sugerindo: `caller.CallForm(anotherForm)`, requer que a classe **FormCaller** "conheça" todos os formulários que serão invocados. Veja se posso te ajudar extrair alguma idéia com a implementação abaixo...

Para resolver o problema, eu tinha criado uma classe/enumeração só para descrever os formulários filhos do MDI, mas a manutenção estava muito constante. Resolvi então, mudar de estratégia e criar um padrão que poderia ser reutilizado por qualquer outro MDIParent.

> 1. Criei uma interface que força todo MDIParent conhecer como invocar seus filhos (no meu caso, por índice);
> 2. Implementei a interface numa classe abstrata que executaria os padrões desejados (neste no caso, invocar formulários);
> 3. Herdar a classe abstrata em qualquer MDIParent alvo.

Algo como:

```
public interface IMdiContainer
{
    Form GetCurrentForm(int currentStep);
}

public abstract class MdiContainerBase 
{

    private IMdiContainer _container;
    protected int index;

    public MdiContainerBase(IMdiContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override void OnShow(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShow(e);

        // Call mdiChild from mdiContainer
        ShowMdiChild(_container.GetCurrentForm(index));
    }

    protected override void NextForm()
    {
        ShowMdiChild(_container.GetCurrentForm(++index));
    }

    protected override void PrevForm()
    {
        ShowMdiChild(_container.GetCurrentForm(--index));
    }

    private void ShowMdiChild(Form form)
    {
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
    }

    // and so on...
}

public class MyCustomMdiContainer : MdiContainerBase, IMdiContainer
{
    public MyCustomMdiContainer() : base(this)
    {
    }

    // implementation forced by interface
    public Form GetForm(int index)
    {
        switch(index)
        {
            case 1:
                return new Form1();

            case 2:
                return new Form2();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Assim você pode criar tudo o que precisa na interface... Só precisará criar o switch... Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não entendi exatamente o que você quer fazer.
Os forms que você vai chamar serão de form explicita?, ou seja:

```
FormCadastro novoform = new FormCadastro():
```

Ou você ainda não sabe qual form será chamado?
Se for esse o caso, você pode utilizar CreateInstance. Nesse caso, os forms devem estar na DLL do projeto.
using System;

```
class DynamicInstanceList
{
    private static string instanceSpec = "System.EventArgs;System.Random;" +
        "System.Exception;System.Object;System.Version";

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] instances = instanceSpec.Split(';');
        Array instlist = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), instances.Length);
        object item;
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
        {
            // create the object from the specification string
            Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of: {0}", instances[i]);
            item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instances[i]));
            instlist.SetValue(item, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nObjects and their default values:\n");
        foreach (object o in instlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type:     {0}\nValue:    {1}\nHashCode: {2}\n",
                o.GetType().FullName, o.ToString(), o.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```